# Looping over multi-upload form fields

Tags: php, file, loops, upload

I have a multi-file upload form in PHP.
I loop over the file input boxes like so:

while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES['images']['name']))

I added a description box, so now I have description[] as another field.

How can I loop over both the files and the description boxes?

Comment: do a `var_dump()` of $_FILES to make sure you're iterating the right thing.. should you be iterating ['name']??

Answer (score 1):

You can try working on both simultaneously

```
foreach ( $_FILES ['image'] ['tmp_name'] as $key => $val ) {
    $fileName = $_FILES ['image'] ['name'] [$key]; // FileName
    $fileDesc = $_POST['description'][$key]; // Work on Description
}
```

Comment: I guess he meant something like `$_POST['description'][$key]` instead of unassigned $description

Answer (score 0):

Most probably both have correspondily same keys. So

```
foreach($_FILES['images']['name']) as $k=>$v)
{
    echo $v."<br>";
    echo $description[$k]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to iterate: `foreach( $_FILES as $file ) { ... }`